# accepts_nested_attributes_for rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a model with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but if I save the main model and it fails validation, the subelements are still saved and associated. How can I prevent the nested elements from being saved unless the parent object successfully saves? The object has already been created by this point.

Here's what I've tried:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :security_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :security_questions
  validates_length_of :security_questions, minimum: 3, maximum: 3, if: :creation_finished?
end

class SecurityQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :security_questions
  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

Unfortunately, if I attempt to create the user (and I provide security questions) and it fails to create, any future attempts will trigger an error due to there being too many security questions.

Comment: As far as I know `#save` does nothing if model validation fails. Can you show us the code where you save the model?

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer I actually used an update rather than a save.